# PHP : Connection aborted while scraping data from site

Tags: php

I am scraping from a site which list some products and I have save the product page urls in the database and looping through the table for getting the url and using the simple html dom parser for scraping I am using the following code.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ignore_user_abort(true);
require_once('lib/simple_html_dom.php');
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
ini_set('max_input_time ', '99999');
$catid = $_REQUEST['catid']; //passing category id from url
//getting category product url's from DB.
$query = mysql_query("select * from cat_prod where catid='".$catid."' ") or die(mysql_error());
if($query){

    while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

        $html = file_get_html($arr['purl']);

            if(is_object($html)){
                $i=1;   
                foreach ( $html->find('h1') as $elem ){
                    if(is_object($elem) && isset($elem))
                        echo $i.' : '.$elem->plaintext.'<br/>';
                    if($i==2) exit;
                $i++;   
                }
                $html->clear();
                unset($html);
            }
    }
}

?>
```

When I die the execution after one iteration its fine but for more than one it throwing connection aborted error.

Comment: How many requests are you making to scrape the remote site? Perhaps the remote site has a firewall that's blocking requests because it's detecting too many connections from one source (your site).

Comment: Arg! Passing raw user input to SQL string.  This is an SQL injection attack waiting to happen!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a sleep in the loop.  You are possibly hammering the website with a DOS attack.

Also your script has a SQL injection problem with `$catid`